# I don't really understand when to use ViewDataBinding.invalidateAll() in data binding

Tags: android, methods, data-binding, invalidation

I don't understand what invalidateAll() actually do when using data binding. The documentations says:

> Invalidates all binding expressions and requests a new rebind to refresh UI.

But I don't really understand. What does it mean "invalidates all binding expressions" in this context?
I have found this method on some other code and if I remove the method the code works the same.

Answer (score 0):

`invalidateAll()` is used to refresh the bind data.

For example, you change the value of a bound data while listening to an event, and this value can be refreshed through this function